# Sync Events to available mail accounts in iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5

I am trying to sync Events added by my code in calendar application to available mail accounts. I just wanted to confirm that, is it possible in ios5?? I am trying to search for it but not able to find good solution for this. Any one having idea about this??

And I have one more question to ask that is, I am using ios5 new function which create new calendar in iphone's calendar application. Whenever I creates calendar of type local, I am able to create it. But I cant see that calendar in calendar list. Because of some reason it gets hide. Any idea about this??

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

First add MessageUI framework in your poject and import these two in your file

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>
```

Then make a button to refer mail in xid and link it with a IBAction (like below):

```
-(IBAction)emailSettings:(id)sender{

Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));
if (mailClass != nil)
{
    // check whether the current device is configured for sending emails
    if ([mailClass canSendMail])
    {
        [self displayComposerSheet];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"EMAIL" message:@"No Settings For Email" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
      }
    }

}

-(void)displayComposerSheet 
{
  MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [picker setSubject:@"StampedeBreakfast!"];

    // Set up recipients
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"first@example.com"]; 
    NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com", nil]; 
    NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"third@example.com"]; 

    [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
    [picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];  
    [picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

    // Fill out the email body text
    NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hey! This is my Email Body"];
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];


    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
 }

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{   

switch (result)
{
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        NSLog( @"Result: canceled");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        NSLog(@"Result: saved");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
         NSLog(@"Result: sent");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        NSLog( @"Result: failed");
        break;
    default:
         NSLog(@"Result: not sent");
        break;
}

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

hope this will help you!!

Comment: this will help you to compose a mail and make body according to you event in calander

Comment: so you want to save them directly into draft

Comment: Hey have you heard about google calendar? which is linked to your gmail account?? By adding that gmail account into your iPhone results all events which you have added from web can display on your iPhone's calendar application. I want to do exactly like this. I will add events to Calendar app using Eventkit framework and then I want to sync those newly added events to my gmail account so that I can see those events on my gmail account.